# Why is my discord bot not answering any commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have already made a few bots and it was going well when one day suddenly one of the bots I was working on stopped responding. I made a new simple bot to test out if my code had any problems, but the bot commands didn't work out. I tried various ways tuning settings on the developer portal and in the bot code but nothing seems to help.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(commands_prefix = commands.when_mentioned_or('!'), 
description = 'The simplest and stupidest bot.', intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
     print('Bot online.')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx:commands.Context):
     await ctx.reply(f'My latency is {round(client.latency, 3)} ms.')

client.run('Token')
```

The only code that works is the on_ready function. Nothing else does anything, not even the help command. Nor does it show any errors in the command line.

I have message intents turned on.

The only difference I get now is that previously when I turned the bot off by using Ctrl+C, it showed me a Runtime error and stated that the event loop was closed. Basically, it showed a few lines of error before turning off. But now, it doesn't show anything, no errors, not even a single line.

Comment: did you give it permission to write?

in your discord developer page https://discord.com/login?redirect_to=%2Fdevelopers%2Fapplications

and in your discord server

(in my case i gave it the rank of administrator)

Comment: It already had the administrator rank since the beginning.

Comment: What is your discord.py version? Are you swallowing any errors (have you overwritten `on_error`-type things)?

Answer (score 0):

Change @client.event to @client.listen().

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).